# xmp php mysql хелп

Tags: php, mysql, xml, phpmyadmin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]надо данные из xml записать в mysql

Вот набросал код в php, но почему-то переменные пустые[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

xml :

Comment: xml: <goods>
<good sh="123" name="qwe" ed="oopopop" cost="123456"/>
<good sh="001" name="asdf" ed="zxcczxc" cost="56742"/>
</goods>

Comment: Linux? я думал только я один им пользуюсь . По вопросу: у вас же закоментированно там

Comment: @LenovoID  он ругается на эту строчку.

Comment: Код и исходные данные нельзя публиковать скриншотами. Они должны быть в текстовом виде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пройтись по сущностям можо так:

```
foreach ($sxml->good as $good) {
    $sh = $good['sh'];
    $name = $good['name'];
    $ed = $good['ed'];
    $cost = $good['cost'];

    // Или можно в одну строчку, если последовательность аттрибутов гарантированно не меняеться
    // list($sh, $name, $ed, $cost) = $good->attributes();

    printf("%s %s %s %s <br/>", $sh, $name, $ed, $cost);
}
```